# Duplicate fragment on Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to replace a fragment using `newInstance()`:

**MainActivity.onCreate()**

```
Fragment telaInicialFragment = TelaInicialFragment.newInstance(usuario);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, telaInicialFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**TelaInicialFragment.newInstance()**

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("usuario", usuario);
TelaInicialFragment fragment = new TelaInicialFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
```

My **activity_main.xml** is composed of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this line: 
`fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, telaInicialFragment);` with `android.R.id.content` my fragment appears duplicated on MainActivity:
[image: duplicated_fragment.png]

When I change to id of FrameLayout (component tree of this screen is after the exception):

`fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framelayout_tela_inicial, telaInicialFragment);`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nextapp.next/com.nextapp.next.activity.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c009b (com.nextapp.next:id/framelayout_tela_inicial) for fragment TelaInicialFragment{e034022 #0 id=0x7f0c009b}
```

**fragment_tela_inicial.xml component tree**
[image: component_tree.png]

And doesn't matter (in this case) if I use `fragmentTransaction.add()` or `fragmentTransaction.replace()`.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: The layout you are trying to add the fragment to must be visible from your main activity (i.e. inside your main layout xml)

Comment: Since you have a view pager though... you should be adding fragments in the view page adapter (which needs to be sub classed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a fragment adapter for your ViewPager.

Create a subclass similar to the following...

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FirstFragment.newInstance();
        case 1: 
            return SecondFragment.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```

Set it to your pager using the `pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());`

Comment: I already have a Adapter for fragments not found relevant quote it here, anyway In this case you say to pass the argument to the adapter and instantiate it in the adapter class? Also, I do not understand why you negative the question.

Comment: I didn't down vote you. And you don't have any code showing you're use of an adapter for your viewpager.